# Printing from array with button

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, button, printing

I´m trying to print from an array with a button. The users are supposed to press the button and a text box is showing up. But nothing happens when I press the button. Does anyone see the problem?

The button is made in html.

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  //HTML objects
  let lenkerBtn;
  let mainContent;

  //bildeliste
  let tekst = ["Her kan du lese om lenker. Bare vent et øyeblikk :)"];

  let init = function () { 

    let setHTMLObjects = function () {
      lenkerBtn = document.getElementById("lenkerBtn");
      mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");
    }(); //end setEvents

    let setEvents = function(){
      lenkerBtn.onclick = vislenker;
    }(); //end setEvents

  }(); //end init                              

  function visLenker () {
    let antallTekst = tekst.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < tekst; i++) {
      document.getElementById("tekstOmLenker").innerHTML += ("<li>" + tekst[i] + "</li>");
    }
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be in

```
 function visLenker(){
       let antallTekst = tekst.length;
       for(var i = 0; i < tekst; i++){
        document.getElementById("tekstOmLenker").innerHTML += ("<li>" + tekst[i] + "</li>");
   }
```

where you declare

```
i < tekst
```

instead of

```
i < antallTekst
```

It is usually best to avoid declaring one-time use variables, so ( i < tekst.length ) would probably be a cleaner form.

If that does not solve the problem you might want to post some of the relevant Html too.

Comment: Here is my HTML: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

<title>Universiell utforming</title>

</head>
<body>
   
    <div>
        <h1>Lær om universiell utforming</h1>
    </div>
    
    <section>
        <input id="lenkerBtn" type="button" value="Les om lenker">
        <ul id="tekstOmLenker"></ul>
    </section>

   <main id="main-content"></main>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

This line of code seems to be wrong

```
 for (var i = 0; i < tekst; i++) {
```

Since `tekst` is an array not a number